# output a variable value using echo command

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I want to output number of lines in text file.So I am using echo command but I am getting filename along with number of lines when I run the following code:

```
echo "$page" > t
total="$(wc -l t)"
echo "$total"
```

Output:
    162 t

Note: Number of lines in file "t" are 162 only.

Comment: This is a duplicate but here you go: `wc -l < file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use `wc -l FILENAME`, it would always print file name along with a number.

```
wc -l /etc/hosts
34 /etc/hosts
```

In order NOT to print the file name, you can use `cat` and pipe it's output to `wc -l` as follows:

```
cat /etc/hosts | wc -l
34
```

So, in your case, if you could change the `total` variable to `total=$(cat t | wc -l)`, you should get only a number saved in the variable `total`.

On the other hand, you can use `cut` or `awk` in order to extract the number part from the `wc -l t` part as follows:

`wc -l t | cut -d " " -f1`

`wc -l t | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: You don't need to call `cat` for this, just use shell redirection, as don_crissti commented above.

Comment: @glennjackman - Noted. Thanks for your input. Also let me know if I am supposed to make that correction in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a flag to prevent wc from printing the filename, but with `cut` you can just cut out your number:

```
wc -l filename  | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: The funny thing is that symmetrical `cut -d' ' -f1 filename | wc -l` works too :)

Comment: Yes, but this does something completely different. The reason why it works is just that you feed the content to wc through stdin so it can't print any filename (it doensn't know the filename), so ```cat filename | wc -l``` has exactly the same result